# App Store: iOS9 works, iOS8 gives “Unable to download application. <App> could not be installed at this time”

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, xcode7, code-signing

I'm getting the infamous “Unable to download application.  could not be installed at this time” error when my app is downloaded from the App Store on iOS8. The app downloads correctly on iOS9.

A look at the console logs during install doesn't reveal much, unfortunately. This is the relevant portion of the install log from a failing install on iOS 8:

```
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus itunesstored[9645] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios with icons
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus installd[9655] <Notice>: 0x100484000 -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-4374795983805385212.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 9645)
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus installd[9655] <Notice>: 0x100484000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=1328, ShortVersion=(null)>
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus installd[9655] <Notice>: 0x100484000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/84774358-990D-42DA-BBAA-05CEA0767766
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus installd[9655] <Notice>: 0x100484000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:withError:]: Made container live for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E00E811D-BF97-4C50-8979-C95D816AE914
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus installd[9655] <Notice>: 0x100484000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.11s; Overall: 0.12s
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus itunesstored[9645] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x15921bc70> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios (Placeholder) withPhase:3
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus lsd[8860] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x13555dfc0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 3
Oct 22 11:19:29 iPhone-6-Plus itunesstored[9645] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x1590b3740> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
```

The only thing that looks off there is the `Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=1328, ShortVersion=(null)>`. The version is actually "1.0.8" and the short version is actually "1328". Could this be causing the issue?

This is the relevant portion of a successful install on iOS 9:

```
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [Download]: Adding download(s): -5384935931379580938
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12d852330> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios <(null) *Not found in database*>
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-5384935931379580938.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 108)
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller _extractPackageWithError:]: Incoming install at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.wn3ByM/extracted/-5384935931379580938.app had class 3; changing to class 4
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=(null), ShortVersion=(null)>
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AA0FE5E8-F0BA-4554-BBE8-F844214BE127
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1256BD0E-DBDE-4D60-80A5-D27303F56413
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.00s; Overall: 0.09s
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x12c5a7b20> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1256BD0E-DBDE-4D60-80A5-D27303F56413/-5384935931379580938.app> withPhase:3
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x12da17570> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Oct 22 11:47:44 iPhone ondemandd[162] <Error>: Application with ID: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios was installed, but it doesn't appear to have a bundle URL, we are taking no action on this.
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [Download]: Adding download(s): -5384935931379580938
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone AppStore[165] <Warning>: ITML <Error>: Unknown timer: <null>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [Download]: Starting task: 3 with priority: 300 for download: -5384935931379580938 bundleIdentifier: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios in session: com.apple.itunesstored.com.apple.AppStore.default
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12d9346f0> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1256BD0E-DBDE-4D60-80A5-D27303F56413/-5384935931379580938.app> with icons
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-5384935931379580938.app" type Placeholder requested by itunesstored (pid 108)
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIInstaller _extractPackageWithError:]: Incoming install at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2MlBDe/extracted/-5384935931379580938.app had class 3; changing to class 4
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=1328, ShortVersion=(null)>
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8B03946E-BA87-47B0-8B99-0F790775A5E5
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5F331BC2-E9C6-4E95-A06F-62A26C2EA1F5
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e247000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.00s; Overall: 0.07s
Oct 22 11:47:53 iPhone ondemandd[162] <Error>: Application with ID: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios was installed, but it doesn't appear to have a bundle URL, we are taking no action on this.
Oct 22 11:47:56 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x12da90760> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5F331BC2-E9C6-4E95-A06F-62A26C2EA1F5/-5384935931379580938.app> withPhase:0
Oct 22 11:47:56 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x127d33860> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [Download]: Download task did finish: 3 for download: -5384935931379580938
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Installing download: -5384935931379580938 with step(s): Install
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Installing software package with bundleID: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios: bundleVersion: 1328 path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-5384935931379580938/8956830454785498068
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12c6e5e90> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5F331BC2-E9C6-4E95-A06F-62A26C2EA1F5/-5384935931379580938.app>
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x12c6e5e90> co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5F331BC2-E9C6-4E95-A06F-62A26C2EA1F5/-5384935931379580938.app> withPhase:1
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x127d33860> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.5900 / Completed: 59 of 100   to 1
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-5384935931379580938/8956830454785498068" type Customer requested by itunesstored (pid 108)
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=1328, ShortVersion=1.0.8>
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/37FAE64E-298B-4DF7-876F-4A7D75B50443
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F1CB450-2DB5-46B8-BDCF-601C87F49C26
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.01s, Verifying: 0.23s; Overall: 0.44s
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios.Installing - <NSProgress: 0x12c6b5e50> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 100 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Install complete for download: -5384935931379580938 result: Success
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Updating placeholder for download: -5384935931379580938 bundleIdentifier: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios.Loading - <NSProgress: 0x12d8f4480> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 1 of 1   called, removing progress from cache
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone itunesstored[108] <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Placeholder updated for download: -5384935931379580938 bundleIdentifier: co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios success: 1
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:userInfo.installState could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:54 iPhone lsd[79] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In observeValueForKeyPath:fractionCompleted could not find parent progress for co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios, it may have been removed
Oct 22 11:52:55 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Installed apps did change.
Added: {(
    "co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios"
)}
Removed: {(
)}
Modified: {(
)}
```

On iOS 9, the `Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=...` line appears *three times*, the first is

```
MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=(null), ShortVersion=(null)>
```

Followed by

```
[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=1328, ShortVersion=(null)>
```

And finally the more correct-looking

```
[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=co.{{ my_app }}.{{ my_app }}.ios; Version=1328, ShortVersion=1.0.8>
```

Confusingly, each time it is followed by a matching `[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful`, so I'm not sure if this is actually a clue or not :/

Any ideas where else I can look? Thanks.

Comment: The store is having problems, go get a cup of coffee (for a day or two) :)

Comment: make sure there isn't a debug build already on the device and try again? Although I think that error is different but hey, its worth a try :D

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we're seeing the issue with people who've never had TestFlight installed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to wait for two three days... Just wait!!!

Comment: Well you and @matt were actually right, I just checked and it's working again :/